# What specs to look for in a router to connect multiple Apple and non-Apple devices efficiently?

Tags: wifi, router, network

I have a router at the moment that keeps dropping Airplay connection between different iOS devices. I'm trying to find a better router that can withstand the amount of interference from various devices such as multiple iPhones, iPads, MacBooks, Windows laptops, AppleTV, and a TV.

I know the iPad (1 and 2) and the iPhone cannot use 5 Ghz wireless signals, yet the AppleTV and retina MacBook Pro do. So I am not sure if I need to get a dual band router that can send both 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz, or just stick to 2.4 Ghz single band transmitter.

I would appreciate your advice for what to look for in a router to achieve what I mentioned?

Comment: This is such a generic question that's in no way apple-specific, and is therefore off topic. "Apple devices" are WiFi devices like any other (although they usually have a higher adoption rate of dual band than most other OEMs).

Comment: If you read carefully, I mentioned that airplay via the AppleTV keeps dropping because of my current router, and would like a router that allows all devices to connect as well as the ATV efficiently with no dropped connections. Please read before commenting.

Comment: That still has nothing to do specifically with an Apple Device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you expect to get out of a router.

I just use an AirPort Extreme, and at any time there are at least 7 devices connected, 3 of which are on the 5ghz band, 3 are on 2.4ghz, and the other 2 are wired.

It's possibly the most reliable router I've had, and is incredibly easy to configure and maintain.

I also have 2 hard drives and a printer connected to it's USB port via a USB hub.

The only issue I have with it is that it doesn't play nicely if I try to set-up an incoming VPN connection on my Windows server, however it does work if I run a VPN on an OS X server I borrowed to test.

Comment: I purchased a D-Link router with Dual band 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz as you mentioned. Turns out having a router with dual band is very important to sustain all the incoming wireless signals. My ATV does not drop connections now and all the windows and apple devices are connected wired/less efficiently. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a little OT, but you might want to look at a router compatible with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices).

I have a [Linksys WRT350N](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H96IN2), a few years old now, and AirTunes to my previous-generation AirPort Express would drop out constantly when the Linksys still had its stock firmware; when I moved last year and went to a 25Mbit cable service, the router would often freeze and reboot itself.  Installed DD-WRT and everything has been absolutely perfect since.

I've also replaced my AirPort Express with a new [Philips AirPlay wireless speaker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005HY4UJ6) and it's never dropped.

Mac Pro (2008) on gigabit serving Plex etc; 2-3 Mac and PC laptops, 2 iPhone 4Ses, my iPad 2 - none ever have trouble.